# Switching Tabs inside Grid changes tabs size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Grid in which I have a tab control. Now the tab control has one tab open always, called the "controls" and you can add **panel** as a different tab. Now if you switch the tab, the **panel** tends to reduce its size as there is no content present in it and I want that panel to remain the size of "Control Panel".

Here the code snippet of it.

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
<Button x:Name="Add_button"/>
<Button x:Name="Close_button"/>
</DockPanel>

<TabControl Grid.Row="1" 
          Padding="0"
          Margin="1"
          x:Name="_AllTabs" 
          BorderBrush="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PanelList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPanel}">

<ScrollViewer>
<-- panel screen --> 
<GraphicContentControl Root="{Binding PanelModel}"/>
</ScrollViewer>


</TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I'm Expecting GraphicContentControl to reamin of the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because your tab does not have a defined size just a margin, so its size depends on the size of the grid row size in which it is.

And since that grid row size is in "Auto", then it adjust according to the
content size. Since the panel has no content, the grid row shrink, shrinking the panel size with it.

If you want things to remain a certain size, you have to give them the width/height value you want, or at least one of the two if the other does not have to stay fixed.

Comment: is there a way, apart from giving a specific size, for panel grid to remain of the same size as control grid ?

Comment: You could, in theory, programmatically read the control grid width/height value and then write them to the panel griddimensions value when it is created. You'll have to find the right time to do so. For example you could do that in a callback function that is called at the creation of the panel grid and each time the control grid change size. that would avoid you the need to fix the dimension of the control grid but will ensure the panel grid will always follow its size.